# Using lamma_index and qdrant, how do I query from a specific document_id from qdrant database?

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, qdrant

Using SimpleDirectoryReader we can index content of all files in a directory.
And while queriying, it searches the entire collection in qdrant to find top-K similarities..

```
chat_engine = index.as_chat_engine(
service_context=service_context,
chat_mode=ChatMode.REACT, verbose=False)

chat_engine.chat("Who is wiki?")
```

I want to query, but from a specific document, even though I have indexed all documents  in the directory. How do i do it?

Comment: Do you have the text of the document you search or the ID? In any event, you can likely use the `recommend` API which lets you do a two-step search (get the point by filter or ID, then search for similar points).